# Find the number of commas in a file in Pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

File has 'N' number of rows and each row has 3 attributes separated by commas. 
Ex: Input FileX has the fields  `name,number,amt`.
**Content**

```
abc,123,123
bcd,345,234
cde,349,900
```

**Output:**
6

i.e How to find the number of commas?

Answer (score 0):

Load the file so that the entire record in stored in 1 field.Then tokenize the line into letters.Filter only the commas,group and count commas.

```
A = load '/home/user/fileX';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE($0,'','|'), '|')) as letter;
C = filter B BY (letter == ',');
D = group C by letter;
E = foreach D generate COUNT(C), group;--Note:if you want only the count then remove the group and generate COUNT(C)
DUMP E;
```

Output

[image: Output]